# Prove that ideal $I = \langle X^2,X+1\rangle$ is principal or not (in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ )

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I tried the following $$I = \langle X^2,X+1\rangle =\langle X^2,X+1,X^2+2(X+1)\rangle =\langle X^2,X+1,(X+1)^2+1 \rangle$$

Yet no matter how I arrange it, I cannot obtain $1$. Can someone help me out?

Comment: An ideal in **which** ring?

Comment: First in Z and then in Q! Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: **Hint:** $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ is a PID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$-(X+1)^2+X^2+2(X+1)=1$. So, your ideal contains $1$.

Comment: So, the ideal is principal for both Z[X] and Q[x]

Comment: @Eduard6421 Your ideal is the ideal generated by $1$, so, yes, it is principal (in both cases).

Answer (score 4):

Note that $I$ contains
$$X^2+(X+1)(-X+1) =1$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

From your [prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2326276/242) $(x+1,f(x)) = (1)\iff f(-1)\mid 1$ which is true for $\,f(x) = x^2.$

**Remark** $ $ The other answers are essentially a special case of the proof in the prior question.

If you wish to gain further *algorithmic* insight on how to perform such calculations then follow the link I [gave here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/613988/242) on *Hermite Normal Form.*

Answer (score 0):

I am using $\langle f,g \rangle = \langle r,g \rangle$ when $f=h\,g+r$ for $h,r \in K[X]$.

So lets do the polynomial division:

```
X^2        : X + 1     = X - 1
X^2 + X
-------
    - X
    - X - 1
    -------
          1
```

So we get $\langle 1,g \rangle$ for both $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, or simply $\langle 1 \rangle$.